# sliderInput doesn't format date labels (anymore)

Tags: r, shiny

I have this app that used to correctly format dates in the labels of the input slide. Now (not sure since when) it returns the Unix Timestamp. Has something changed in how the `sliderInput` process dates?

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("date_range", 
              NA, as.Date("2016-01-31"), as.Date('2016-12-04'),
              value = c(as.Date("2016-01-31"), as.Date('2016-12-04')), 
              step = 1, sep = ""
  )
)

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

I tested it both on OSX and on a Shiny Server (on Ubuntu). Same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove `sep` argument from your `sliderInput` you get the expected output. Your code will look as follows:

```
library(shiny)
  ui <- fluidPage(
    sliderInput(inputId = "date_range", 
                NA, as.Date("2016-01-31"), as.Date('2016-12-04'),
                value = c(as.Date("2016-01-31"), as.Date('2016-12-04')), 
                step = 1
    )
  )

  # Server logic
  server <- function(input, output) {
  }

  # Run the application 
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The output is as follows:
[image]